# Mocking global function using gmock-global

Tags: googletest, googlemock

Currently I am learning how to use google test and google mock frameworks in order to create unit tests. I found this framework - gmock-global, with which I can mock global functions. I read the README file in the github repository (https://github.com/apriorit/gmock-global). My problem is that when I try to use the macro

```
MOCK_GLOBAL_FUNC2(sum2(int a, int b), int(int, int))
```

the compiler gives me this error:

> Invalid initialization of non-const reference of type
>   'testing::internal::MockSpec&' from an rvalue of type
>   'testing::internal::MockSpec'  UniGener001     line 98,
>   external location:

Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Is this a typo or are you actually writing `MOCK_GLOBAL_FUNC2 (MOCK_GLOBAL_FUNC2(sum2, int(int, int)))` with `MOCK_GLOBAL_FUNC2` in it **twice**? If so, that might be your issue.

Comment: I am writing:
MOCK_GLOBAL_FUNC2(sum2(int a, int b), int(int, int));

Comment: Please ensure that you provide the correct code sample next time. There is a **world** of difference between `MOCK_GLOBAL_FUNC2 (MOCK_GLOBAL_FUNC2(sum2, int(int, int)))` and `MOCK_GLOBAL_FUNC2(sum2, int(int, int))` and `MOCK_GLOBAL_FUNC2(sum2(int a, int b), int(int, int))` ...

Answer (score 0):

> I am writing: MOCK_GLOBAL_FUNC2(sum2(int a, int b), int(int, int));

This is probably the issue. Taking a look at the readme:
If `int sum2(int a, int b)` is the signature of the function you want to mock, then you should write `MOCK_GLOBAL_FUNC2(sum2, int(int, int))`

The first parameter of the macro is (only!) the function name, and the second parameter is the functions signature.